# How to get only positive value while subtracting in swift?

Tags: swift, variables, subtraction

I want to get the value of zero while the larger value is subtracted from the smaller one.
For eg:

```
var a = 10
var b = 3
var c = b-a
```

and it should print c = 0 instead of c = -8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max(b-a, 0)`, which will return `b-a` in case the result is positive and 0 otherwise.

```
let a = 10
let b = 3
let c = max(b-a,0)
```